# Polynomial functions that are products of linear ones

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider $n$ linear functions $l_i : V \rightarrow \mathbb{k}$, $i=1, \ldots, n$,  where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field ($k = \mathbb{C}$ for simplicity) and $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{k}$. Consider the polynomial function of degree $n$ over $V$  defined by the (point-wise) product:
$$f_{l_1 ,\ldots, l_n} = l_1 \cdots l_n^. $$

Now let $l_i^j$ be linear functions for $i=1,\ldots, n$ and $j=1, \ldots, d$ for some $n,d$. My question is: could you give me conditions on the $l_i^j$'s for which the $d$ polynomial functions $f_{l_1^1, \ldots, l_n^1}, \ldots, f_{l_1^d, \ldots, l_n^d}$ are linearly independent (as functions)?

Thank you in advance for your help.